# Wrong Resolution on Mac OS X 10.14 Mojave

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I don't reach to set the correct resolution on mac OS X Mojave. The only allowed resolution is 1024x768, but i have to use Logic and this resolution is too low.
My monitor is full HD!!!

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking

Comment: You are on the wrong forum for this but option click and you will get more resolution options.

Comment: This belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm a newbie in macOS. If i click on "System" and then i try to find a correct resolution it only appears "1024x768", while i need to use other resolution for obvious reasons.